# A simple query on numerical optimization.

Tags: numerical-methods

Newton's method for $\frac1{\sqrt{a}}$ proceeds by iterating minimizing $\frac1{x^2}-a$.

Why cant I do $\frac{x-ax^3}2$?

Infact why cant I replace $2$ by any $k\in\Bbb R_{>0}$?

Comment: Why do you need to divide by 2?  Does that change the minima (if there are any)?

Comment: Because you introduce another zero to the problem $x = 0$, which complicates things numerically

Comment: Please reformulate your question. Your term as function does not have a minimum, the root of your term is $\frac1{\sqrt{a}}$ which indeed Newton's method will find.

Comment: @LutzL $\frac{\frac1{\sqrt a}-a\frac1{\sqrt{a^3}}}k=\frac{\frac1{\sqrt a}-\frac1{\sqrt a}}k=0$.

Comment: That's what I said, your term is zero at $\frac1{\sqrt{a}}$. Which contradicts at least two statements in your question.

Comment: @LutzL ok corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using $f(x)=x^d-ax^{2+d}$ the Newton method iterates
$$
x_{\it next} = x - \frac{x^d-ax^{2+d}}{dx^{d-1}-(d+2)ax^{d+1}}
=x·\frac{(d+1)ax^2-(d-1)}{(d+2)ax^2-d}
$$
where for $d=0$, $d=-2$ and $d=-\frac12$ you will rediscover some well-known methods for square root approximation.

Comment: So both are right?

Comment: I dont follow your answer.

Comment: That depends on what the question was. The methods differ in their basin of convergence, restriction on the use of division and order of convergence.

Comment: could you please specifically comment on my two expressions?

Comment: There are no equations in your question. The can be easily identified by the equality sign $=$ which is not to be found in the entire text.

Comment: Please explain in more words or formulas what you mean with "replace $2$ by any $k$". And how someone or something is trying to prevent you from doing it. It is perfectly legal to consider instead of $f(x)=0$ the equation $f(x)·g(x)=0$. One needs to be aware that the roots and poles of $g$ are added to the situation. The Newton step for the modified function is $$x_{\rm next}=x-\frac{f(x)g(x)}{f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)}=x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)+f(x)·(\ln|g(x)|)'},$$ which is also perfectly fine, but will give different iteration sequences than for the unmodified function.